# Regression loss functions incorrect

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying a basic averaging example, but the validation and loss don't match and the network fails to converge if I increase the training time. I'm training a network with 2 hidden layers, each 500 units wide on three integers from the range [0,9] with a learning rate of 1e-1, Adam, batch size of 1, and dropout for 3000 iterations and validate every 100 iterations. If the absolute difference between the label and the hypothesis is less than a threshold, here I set the threshold to 1, I consider that correct. Could someone let me know if this is an issue with the choice of loss function, something wrong with Pytorch, or something I'm doing. Below are some plots:

```
val_diff = 1
acc_diff = torch.FloatTensor([val_diff]).expand(self.batch_size)
```

Loop 100 times to during validation:

```
num_correct += torch.sum(torch.abs(val_h - val_y) < acc_diff)
```

Append after each validation phase:

```
validate.append(num_correct / total_val)
```

Here are some examples of the (hypothesis, and labels):

```
[...(-0.7043088674545288, 6.0), (-0.15691305696964264, 2.6666667461395264),
 (0.2827358841896057, 3.3333332538604736)]
```

I tried six of the loss functions in the API that are typically used for regression:

**torch.nn.L1Loss(size_average=False)**
[image]

**torch.nn.L1Loss()**
[image]

**torch.nn.MSELoss(size_average=False)**
[image]

**torch.nn.MSELoss()**
[image]

**torch.nn.SmoothL1Loss(size_average=False)**
[image]

**torch.nn.SmoothL1Loss()**
[image]

Thanks.

Network code:

```
class Feedforward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, topology):
        super(Feedforward, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim     = topology['features']
        self.num_hidden    = topology['hidden_layers']
        self.hidden_dim    = topology['hidden_dim']
        self.output_dim    = topology['output_dim']
        self.input_layer   = nn.Linear(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim)
        self.hidden_layer  = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.hidden_dim)
        self.output_layer  = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim)
        self.dropout_layer = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)


    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size()[0]
        feat_size  = x.size()[1]
        input_size = batch_size * feat_size

        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(input_size, self.hidden_dim).cuda()
        hidden = self.input_layer(x.view(1, input_size)).clamp(min=0)

        for _ in range(self.num_hidden):
            hidden = self.dropout_layer(F.relu(self.hidden_layer(hidden)))

        output_size = batch_size * self.output_dim
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, output_size).cuda()
        return self.output_layer(hidden).view(output_size)
```

Training code:

```
def train(self):
    if self.cuda:
        self.network.cuda()

    dh        = DataHandler(self.data)
    # loss_fn = nn.L1Loss(size_average=False)
    # loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()
    # loss_fn = nn.SmoothL1Loss(size_average=False)
    # loss_fn = nn.SmoothL1Loss()
    # loss_fn = nn.MSELoss(size_average=False)
    loss_fn   = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    losses    = []
    validate  = []
    hypos     = []
    labels    = []
    val_size  = 100
    val_diff  = 1
    total_val = float(val_size * self.batch_size)

    for i in range(self.iterations):
        x, y = dh.get_batch(self.batch_size)
        x = self.tensor_to_Variable(x)
        y = self.tensor_to_Variable(y)

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = loss_fn(self.network(x), y)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Are you zeroing your gradients after updating your weights? That's a common error. Besides, your learning rate seems really high.

Comment: @mexmex aren't i supposed to clear the local gradients each iteration? Isn't that the purpose of optimizer.zero_grad?

Comment: Yes, was just checking that you do in fact! Sorry, if my language was ambiguous.

Comment: Can you show us the neural net code ?

Comment: @Cedias I just updated my post with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've misunderstood how layers in pytorch works, here are a few tips:

- In your forward when you do `nn.Linear(...)` you are definining **new layers** instead of using those you pre-defined in your network `__init__`. Therefore, it cannot learn anything as weights are constantly reinitalized.
- You shouldn't need to call `.cuda()` inside `net.forward(...)` since you've already copied the network on gpu in your `train` by calling `self.network.cuda()`
- Ideally the `net.forward(...)` input should directly have the shape of the first layer so you won't have to modify it. Here you should have `x.size() <=> Linear -- > (Batch_size,  Features)`.

Your forward should look close to this:

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.input_layer(x))
    x = F.dropout(F.relu(self.hidden_layer(x)),training=self.training)
    x = self.output_layer(x)
    return x
```

Comment: So I initialized new layers each iteration to accommodate dynamic inputs. Does pytorch automatically handle dynamic inputs and dynamic batches for you?

Comment: @Soubriquet What do you mean by _dynamic inputs and dynamic batches_ ? Still, using new weights at each input won't work.

Comment: yeah, how do you  dynamically batch

Comment: Batch size can vary between batches seemlessly as the layers aren't expecting fixed-batch inputs.

Comment: So pytorch takes care of that automatically?

Comment: Yes, built-in modules are not expecting a fixed-sized input **between batches**